# OpenGL renders texture all white

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm attempting to render a .png image as a texture. However, all that is being rendered is a white square.

I give my texture a unique int ID called texID, read the pixeldata into a buffer 'image' (declared in the .h file). I load my pixelbuffer, do all of my OpenGL stuff and bind that pixelbuffer to a texture for OpenGL.  I then draw it all using glDrawElements.

Also I initialize the texture with a size of 32x32 when its contructor is called, therefore i doubt it is related to a power of two size issue.

Can anybody see any mistakes in my OpenGL GL_TEXTURE_2D setup that might give me a block white square.

```
 #include "Texture.h"




Texture::Texture(int width, int height, string filename)
{

    const char* fnPtr = filename.c_str(); //our image loader accepts a ptr to a char, not a string
    printf(fnPtr);
    w = width; //give our texture a width and height, the reason that we need to pass in the width and height values manually
    h = height;//UPDATE, these MUST be P.O.T.

    unsigned error = lodepng::decode(image,w,h,fnPtr);//lodepng's decode function will load the pixel data into image vector
    //display any errors with the texture
    if(error)
    {
        cout << "\ndecoder error " << error << ": " << lodepng_error_text(error) <<endl;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<image.size(); i++)
    {
        printf("%i,", image.at(i));

    }

    printf("\nImage size is %i", image.size());

    //image now contains our pixeldata. All ready for OpenGL to do its thing

    //let's get this texture up in the video memory
    texGLInit();
}

void Texture::texGLInit()
{
    //WHERE YOU LEFT OFF: glGenTextures isn't assigning an ID to textures. it stays at zero the whole time
    //i believe this is why it's been rendering white
    glGenTextures(1, &textures);
    printf("\ntexture = %u", textures);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures);//evrything we're about to do is about this texture
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    //glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    //glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    //glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);
    //glDisable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8,w,h,0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &image);
    //we COULD free the image vectors memory right about now.


}

void Texture::draw(point centerPoint, point dimensions)
{
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    printf("\nDrawing block at (%f, %f)",centerPoint.x, centerPoint.y);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures);//bind the texture
    //create a quick vertex array for the primitive we're going to bind the texture to
    printf("TexID = %u",textures);
    GLfloat vArray[8] = 
    {
        centerPoint.x-(dimensions.x/2), centerPoint.y-(dimensions.y/2),//bottom left i0
        centerPoint.x-(dimensions.x/2), centerPoint.y+(dimensions.y/2),//top left i1
        centerPoint.x+(dimensions.x/2), centerPoint.y+(dimensions.y/2),//top right i2
        centerPoint.x+(dimensions.x/2), centerPoint.y-(dimensions.y/2)//bottom right i3
    };

    //create a quick texture array (we COULD create this on the heap rather than creating/destoying every cycle)
    GLfloat tArray[8] = 
    {
        0.0f,0.0f, //0
        0.0f,1.0f, //1
        1.0f,1.0f, //2
        1.0f,0.0f //3
    };

    //and finally.. the index array...remember, we draw in triangles....(and we'll go CW)
    GLubyte iArray[6] =
    {
        0,1,2,
        0,2,3
    };

    //Activate arrays
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    //Give openGL a pointer to our vArray and tArray
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, &vArray[0]);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, &tArray[0]);

    //Draw it all
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &iArray[0]);

    //glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,6);

    //Disable the vertex arrays
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    //done!

    /*glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f,0.0f);
        glVertex2f(centerPoint.x-(dimensions.x/2), centerPoint.y-(dimensions.y/2));
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f,1.0f);
        glVertex2f(centerPoint.x-(dimensions.x/2), centerPoint.y+(dimensions.y/2));
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f,1.0f);
        glVertex2f(centerPoint.x+(dimensions.x/2), centerPoint.y+(dimensions.y/2));
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f,0.0f);
        glVertex2f(centerPoint.x+(dimensions.x/2), centerPoint.y-(dimensions.y/2));
    glEnd();*/
}



Texture::Texture(void)
{
}
Texture::~Texture(void)
{
}
```

I'll also include the main class' init, where I do a bit more OGL setup before this.

```
void init(void)
{
    printf("\n......Hello Guy. \n....\nInitilising");
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);    
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0,XSize,0,YSize);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    myBlock = new Block(0,0,offset);
    glClearColor(0,0.4,0.7,1);


    glLineWidth(2);         // Width of the drawing line
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); 
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    printf("\nInitialisation Complete");

}
```

Update: adding in the main function where I first setup my OpenGL window.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
  glutInit(&argc, argv);    // GLUT Initialization 
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA|GLUT_DOUBLE); // Initializing the Display mode
  glutInitWindowSize(800,600);  // Define the window size
  glutCreateWindow("Gem Miners");   // Create the window, with caption.
        printf("\n========== McLeanTech Systems =========\nBecoming Sentient\n...\n...\n....\nKILL\nHUMAN\nRACE \n");
  init();   // All OpenGL initialization


  //-- Callback functions ---------------------
  glutDisplayFunc(display);
  glutKeyboardFunc(mykey);
  glutSpecialFunc(processSpecialKeys);
  glutSpecialUpFunc(processSpecialUpKeys);
  //glutMouseFunc(mymouse);


  glutMainLoop();   // Loop waiting for event 
}
```

Comment: Let OpenGL create texture IDs for you via `glGenTextures()` instead of telling it which ID to use.

Comment: @genpfault, however my Texture class has multiple instances. If i specify an array for gen textures to put ID's into, will that not be different for every instance? Or is this array assumed by openGL to be static?

Comment: @GuyJoelMcLean: Well, normally you want each texture to have a sifferent ID. You should consider moving that drawing function out of the texture class.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's the usual checklist for whenever textures come out white:

- OpenGL context created and being bound to current thread when attemting to load texture?
- Allocated texture ID using `glGenTextures`?
- Are the parameters `format` and `internal format` to `glTex[Sub]Image…` valid OpenGL tokens allowed as input for this function?
- Is mipmapping being used?

  - YES: Supply all mipmap layers – optimally set `glTexParameteri` GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL and GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, as well as GL_TEXTURE_MIN_LOD and GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LOG.
  - NO: Turn off mipmap filtering by setting `glTexParameteri` GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER to GL_NEAREST or GL_LINEAR.

Comment: Upon debuggin inspection, (and having checked all of the above and added allocating texture ID's by glGenTextures) i've noticed the pixel data being stored in the unsigned char vector 'image' contains mostly relevant numbers (0-255), but also alot of gibberish. i.e. non-alphabetic characters. 
Do you think this could be a problem with  the way the .png file is being saved?

Comment: @GuyJoelMcLean: The texture's appearance should reflect the gibberish you're seeing. So, no it should not be all white.

Comment: you are right, when i printf the vector casting all the components to ints, they print in perfect RGBA format. However, through experimentation I have found that the white block can be coloured using glColor4f() :) can you usually do this with textures?

Comment: @GuyJoelMcLean: Yes textures do combine with vertex colors. In which way exactly is controlled by either a shader or the texture environment parameters (set with glTexEnvi). If the texture is not properly loaded then the default white will combine with the color.

Comment: @GuyJoelMcLean: I'm quite positive, that the problem is, that you try to initialize the texture, when there's no context yet. Difficult to say though, without seeing the rest of your code. Most importantly where Texture is instanciated, and how you create your OpenGL context.

Comment: OK I think you may be right. I remember reading that glGenTextures will return 0 if there is no active context set. And guess what, upon inspection, my 'textures' GLuint that i pass into glGenTextures remains zero forevermore. But I don't understand, I've done plenty of texture rendering with OpenGL before and I dont ever remember having to have managed creating and destroying the contexts myself. However, I'll edit the above post to include where openGL is set up.

Comment: @GuyJoelMcLean: Okay, and where do you instanciate your Texture class? If you do this as a global variable, well there's your problem right there. Global class instances are created before `main` is called i.e. before there's a OpenGL context (which GLUT creates for in the `glutCreateWindow` function).

Comment: Yes they are instantiated as static global variables! That makes sense, I'll try it.

Comment: I FINALLY fixed it. The issue for anybody viewing this page in the future with a similar problem, was as @datenwolf said. I was instantiating my instances of Texture globally in another class. I had to move this to a point in code where they would be created AFTER OpenGL created a context. 
ALSO after fixing this, my texture was fuzzy (as in scrambled pixels) and caused intermittent runtime access violations. This was because in glTexImage2D for my pixel data i was simply passing in a reference to the array i had created for it.  Rather than a reference to the first part of ...

Comment: data.
I was passing it &image, whereas passing it &image[0] fixed the problem. 
I haven't quite managed to get the alpha bits working properly, but overall I'm a VERY happy bunny. Thanks for everyone's time and help.

Comment: I had a similar problem, for me settings GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S/GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T to GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE solved the problem.

Comment: Yup, lot's of error possibilities for white textures. My issue was: create context first before loading textures.