# Why does my OpenGL texture appear white?

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, 2d, textures

I'm trying to get an OpenGL texture to render onscreen in 2D. I know it seems really simple, but I'm an OpenGL newbie and this has been giving me some trouble.

No matter what I try, it is showing up white.

I've seen the other questions like [OpenGL renders texture all white](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867219/opengl-renders-texture-all-white) and checked everything on the checklist, but I can't seem to figure out the source, and I would really appreciate any help.

I'm pretty sure I've just made some stupid mistake somewhere, and have tried scrapping my code and rewriting a couple times.

Here is the code relevant to the window being run from the main method.

```
//Window is a custom wrapper for GLFWwindow
Window thirdwindow(window_width, window_height, "Three");
thirdwindow.show();
thirdwindow.setPosition(300, 300);

ThirdLoop(thirdwindow);
```

Here is ThirdLoop:

```
static void ThirdLoop(Window& win)
{
    GLuint tex = loadBMP("cat.bmp");
    auto size = win.getWindowSize();
    win.beginDraw();
    while (running)
    {
        if (win.isClosing())
            running = false;

        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // Set background color to black and opaque
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);         // Clear the color buffer (background)

        DrawImage(size, tex);
        win.render();

        Update();
    }
}
```

And DrawImage (apologies for the odd indenting here, a copy-paste thing)

```
void DrawImage(const Size<int>& size, GLuint texture) {
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0.0, size.width, 0.0, size.height, -1.0, 1.0);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glPushMatrix();

glLoadIdentity();
glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

// Draw a textured quad
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex3f(0, 100, 0);
glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex3f(100, 100, 0);
glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(100, 0, 0);
glEnd();

glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glPopMatrix();

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glPopMatrix();

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}
```

`loadBMP` was taken from http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-5-a-textured-cube/.

Comment: Have you tried running this through a GPU debugger? Something like [GPU Perf Studio](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/graphics-development/gpu-perfstudio/) if you're using an AMD card; I think NVIDIA has something equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
unsigned int CreateTexture(unsigned int Width, unsigned int Height, unsigned char* Pixels)
{
    unsigned int ID = 0;
    glGenTextures(1, &ID);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ID);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, Width);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, Width, Height, 0, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, Pixels);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, 0);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    return ID;
}

void DestroyTexture(unsigned int ID)
{
    glDeleteTextures(1, &ID);
}

void DrawTexture(unsigned int ID, float X1, float Y1)
{
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ID);
    glColor4ub(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex2f(X1, Y1);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex2f(X1, Y2);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex2f(X2, Y2);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex2f(X2, Y1);
    glEnd();
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

I use the following settings for the window:

```
static float angle = 0.0f;
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();

int w = 800;
int h = 600;
glOrtho(0.0f, w, h, 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
glClearColor(0.0f, 40.0f / 256.0f, 100.0f / 256.0f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glClearDepth(1.0f);

glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);


glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(400, 300, 0);
glScalef(100, 100, 0);
glRotatef(angle, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

if (TextureID == 0)
{
    TextureID = CreateTexture(Width, Height, Pixels); //I used the ImageLoader from the comments that I posted.
}
DrawTexture(TextureID, 0.0f, 0.0f);

glPopMatrix();
++angle;

SwapBuffers(DC);
Sleep(1);
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but it still appears white.

Comment: Whatever you're passing as the pixels might be incorrect OR the format doesn't match BGRA. The bitmap loading function on that site does not SEEK to the pixel offset. It also doesn't handle 24 bit formats.

Comment: Try loading the bitmap with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20595340/loading-a-tga-bmp-file-in-c-opengl it doesn't handle 24 bit bitmaps but at least it seeks to the right offset for the pixels.